# my ssh key is no longer working for gitlab. I have included the verbose output

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

I have been using this instance for several weeks and the last week it does not allow me to do any pushing or pulling from Gitlab. I get "permission denied (public key). I am using ubuntu instance for AWS. The public key is added in my setting on gitlab and I have confirmed that the my name and email address in my global config are correct.

Below is the output from ssh -vvv gitlab.com:

```
Dantes-MBP:.ssh dintomusic$ ssh -vvv gitlab.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'dintomusic'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/dintomusic/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dintomusic/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Please may you edit your question to be a [mcve]?

Comment: edited to add just the parts that could be relevant

Comment: Where is your private key located? The last 9 nines of the output shows SSH did not find any private key to use during authentication.

Comment: i have it locally in my ssh directory

Answer (score 0):

```
Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'dintomusic'
```

That is wrong. With ssh, you always authenticate with the' `git`' technical account.
Only that account has in its home your public key registered in ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys.

So your test should be:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

Check you do have `id_rsa/id_rsa.pub` in `/Users/dintomusic/.ssh/`, with the right permission (600)

---

Note that, with [GitLab 14.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/06/22/gitlab-14-0-released/#ssh-key-expiration-enforced-by-default) (June 2021), *expired* SSH keys would be disabled, which is another possible cause for an SSH key (registered to your account) to not work:

> ### SSH key expiration enforced by default
>
> SSH key expiration enforced by default
>
> Expired SSH keys [added to GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account)
> are now disabled by default. This helps to make your GitLab instance more secure. Previously, expired SSH keys added to GitLab were enabled by default, and could be used unless explicitly disabled by an administrator.
>
> This change affects expired SSH keys used on GitLab.com. If your keys are expired or will expire soon, you need to update the key and any services using them. Our [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html) on SSH keys has helpful steps on how to create a new SSH key.
>
> Self-managed administrators can still [allow the use of expired keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#allow-expired-ssh-keys-to-be-used), similar to how they
> can [allow use of expired](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#allow-expired-personal-access-tokens-to-be-used) personal access tokens.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#enforce-ssh-key-expiration) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/320970).

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my issue after doing the basic initial Gitlab steps of:

```
git init
git add .
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:your-username/your-repository.git
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
```

I made sure my private key files were NOT accesible by others.

```
  sudo chmod 600 id_rsa
```

Then I added

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Finally, I just returned to the basic initial step.

```
 git push origin master
```

and voila, all the files were in the Gitlab repository.

I hope it helps someone.